# Array.first Vs Array.shift in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, shift

I'm essentially going through an exercise for rewriting a basic form of the inject method from the Enumerable module and my solution was not doing anything as I was using #first:

```
def injecting(*acc, &block)
  acc = acc.empty? ? self.first : acc.first
  self.each do |x|
     acc = block.call(acc, x)
  end  
  acc
end
```

I then came across another solution which was using #shift instead of #first and was working just fine:

```
def injecting(*acc, &block)
  acc = acc.empty? ? self.shift : acc.first
  self.each do |x|
    acc = block.call(acc, x)
  end  
  acc
end
```

I know that #first returns the first element of the array but doesn't alter it while #shift returns and alters it, but I'm having a hard time understanding how the below code would still get the desired result if you were to mutate the array by dropping the first element:

```
[1,2,3].injecting { |a,x| a + x } # --> 6
```

Any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks!

Comment: Note that with both you could replace `def injecting(*acc, &block)` with `def injecting(*acc)` and `acc = block.call(acc, x)` with `acc = yield(acc, x)`.  Even though you have stated these are from the Enumerable module, you may want to consider wrapping the first in `module Enumerable` / `end`.  Good question, well-stated.

Comment: Cary that's a lifesaver! I'm in the process of learning blocks in general and I prefer using the yield keyword when possible. I could not incorporate it here, clearly because I was doing something wrong or I don't fully understand it yet but I'll fix that too with time ;) Thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend [this explanation](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby) of blocks, procs and more.

Comment: Just from the sheer number of examples, this looks very good. My night is booked. Thanks Cary!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add one line `p acc` to debug it.

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> module Enumerable
 |   def injecting(*acc, &block)
 |     acc = acc.empty? ? self.shift : acc.first  
 |     p acc  
 |     self.each do |x|  
 |       acc = block.call(acc, x)    
 |     end      
 |     acc  
 |   end    
 | end  
=> nil
>> [1,2,3].injecting { |a,x| a + x } 
1
=> 6
>>
```

When you called the method `injecting` on the array `[1,2,3]`, as `acc` was empty, `sef.shift` gets invoked. Now `acc` is `1`. Now `self` has only `[2,3]`. so the call `self.each..` first pass `2`, and then block gets invoked and the result of `a = x` is assigned to `acc`, whis now holds `3`. So now on the next iteration, from `self` next value passed(`3`), and block gets called again, and perform `a + x` again, so now value of `acc` is `6`. So you got the result `6`.

A one level more debugging :

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> module Enumerable
 |   def injecting(*acc, &block)
 |     acc = acc.empty? ? self.shift : acc.first  
 |     p "acc now holds #{acc}"  
 |     p "elements in self is #{self}"  
 |     self.each do |x|  
 |       acc = block.call(acc, x)    
 |       p "current value of acc is #{acc}"    
 |     end      
 |     acc  
 |   end  
 | end  
=> nil
>> [1,2,3].injecting { |a,x| a + x } 
"acc now holds 1"
"elements in self is [2, 3]"
"current value of acc is 3"
"current value of acc is 6"
=> 6
>>
```

---

[As per OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501506/array-first-vs-array-shift-in-ruby/21501572?noredirect=1#comment32459315_21501572)

> Am I safe assuming that by calling first, is still returning the 1st item but starts the iteration from that item, hence why I would get 7?

Again I would suggest you to add some debugging messages, to see what's going go under-hood. Look below :

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> module Enumerable
 |   def injecting(*acc, &block)
 |     acc = acc.empty? ? self.first : acc.first  
 |     p "acc now holds #{acc}"  
 |     p "elements in self is #{self}"  
 |     self.each do |x|  
 |       acc = block.call(acc, x)    
 |       p "current value of acc is #{acc}"    
 |     end      
 |     acc  
 |   end  
 | end  
=> nil
>> [1,2,3].injecting { |a,x| a + x }
"acc now holds 1"
"elements in self is [1, 2, 3]"
"current value of acc is 2"
"current value of acc is 4"
"current value of acc is 7"
=> 7
>>
```

`self.first` just returns the first element, which is `1`, and get assigned to `acc`. But self didn't get modified. But in case of `self.shift`, that `1` was assigned to `acc` and at the sane time got removed from `self`, and then `self` has `[2,3]`.

Now in this part, `self.each..` code passes 3 values of `self`, which are `1`,`2` and `3`. Now the summation is `6`, and added with `1`, which is the first `acc` value, when `self.first` got called. This is how the final result of `acc` is `7`.

Comment: Thanks Arup! Using the debugging messages does make it a lot clearer. Am I safe assuming that by calling first, is still returning the 1st item but starts the iteration from that item, hence why I would get 7?

Comment: @Maikon Now I hope it is clear!! why one code outputs `6` and the other is `7`.

Comment: Adding useful debugging messages is another tool I'm trying to add to my toolbox. Your answer has cleared up a lot of things. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent answer, Arup.  Good to see you're using Pry.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You told.. and I wouldn't use.. It wouldn't ever be happened.. :)

Comment: Not quite `inject`: `[1,2,3].inject(:+) => 6`, `[1,2,3].injecting(&:+) => 6`, `[1,2,3].injecting(:+) => NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just tried to re implement it as per OP's one.. Thus, it is will perform only addition, where as original `#inject` does a lot's of stuff..

Comment: `[2,3,4].injecting(&:*) => 24`.

Comment: I actually installed and started using Pry today. I assume from your responses, I made the right choice :).

Comment: @CarySwoveland humm!! that's cool.. But I don't know how to make it working `[1,2,3].injecting(:+)` or `[2,3,4].injecting(:*)`.. :(

Comment: @ArupRakshit I like the updated version without the if statement, but does the 0 provide any limitations for the future? If I'm dealing with other types of data?

Comment: @Maikon I removed it, because that was not the actual `#inject` implementation.. a lot's of thing then I need to consider.. because `#inject` does a lots of operation..

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Depends on the version. `Enumerable#inject` originally didn't take a symbol either. The original version in 1.8.6 only took an initial element like this method. (I think I'm showing my age…)

Comment: Thanks, @Chuck.  Arup, I just hit "start" on my stopwatch.  Get to work on it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I've been working on it since yesterday and I think I failed in the same 0 trap, as a friend pointed out it wouldn't work with other operations but you're original version still works with something like this:   `['hi','hello','ho'].injecting { |a,x| a.length > x.length ? a : x } --> 'hello'`